# XML deserialization from XSD with variable XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, deserialization

I have been given an XSD file that represents a huge number of elements and associated attributes.  I have created an CS class using xsd.exe.

The issue is that the xml that is created can contain any or all elements and attributes.

Example XML:

```
<App action="A" id="1" validate="yes"><ProductType id="5885"/><SpecType id="221"/><Qty>1</Qty><PartType id="7212"/><Part>456789</Part></App>
<App action="A" id="2" validate="yes"><ProductType id="5883"/><Qty>1</Qty><PartType id="7211"/><Part>132465</Part></App>
```

Then in my code:

```
protected static void ImportProduct(string filename)
{
var counter = 0;
var xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductList));
var fs = new FileStream(String.Format("{0}{1}", FilePath, filename), FileMode.Open);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
var items = (ProductList)xSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

foreach (var record in items.App)
{
    counter++;

    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}{1}", record.ProductType.id, Environment.NewLine));
    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}{1}", record.Part.Value, Environment.NewLine));

    *if (!record.SpecType.Value.Equals(null))
        Console.Write(String.Format("{0}{1}", record.SpecType.id, Environment.NewLine));
    else
        Console.Write(String.Format("{0}{1}", "No SpecType!", Environment.NewLine));

    if (counter == 10)
        break;
}
```

}

So my question is how I can check for an empty/ non-existent element, per the starred (*) line above.

I cannot change the xsd or source XML files in any way, as they are produced by major manufacturers.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks! Brad

Comment: Whats the problem? Does the xsd say 'minOccurs="0"' for SpecType i.e. the object produced by the xsd.exe contains a nullable SpecType (e.g. int?, or string)? If so, why doesn't your (*) line work? Whats the exception/problem? If the xsd does NOT say 'minOccurs="0"', i would expect that the deserialisation crashes.

Comment: Hi Martin, it does have: <xs:element ref="SpecType" minOccurs="0"/>.  Not sure why it breaks on that line.  Seems like it should, but maybe it is syntax that I have that is not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, XSD.EXE and XML Serialization isn't going to deal with XML like that.

XML of that nature is created because someone thinks it should be easy for humans to read and type in. They don't think about whether machines will be able to use them. It's a mistake that you'll now have to pay for.

The best you could do would be to create an XSLT that will place the elements into some canonical order, then create an XSD representing that order and create classes from the XSD.

Comment: I agree. Data binding works well with simple regular schemas. The bigger the schema and the more "semi-structured" the data becomes, the more clumsy and cumbersome it becomes to use data binding; XSLT and XQuery are much better suited to processing that kind of data.

Comment: OK, very good, guys, thank you.  I am voting this answer up just for the change of direction I am having to make.  It is one of those solutions where they consulted all but the developers.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an XSD you could use the dataset instead of the XML Reader. Then there are a few automatic methods created to check nulls as seen in the below example.

eg. This in an example where CalcualtionAnalysisDS is the XSD.

```
        CalcualtionAnalysisDS ds = new CalcualtionAnalysisDS();
        ds.ReadXml("calc.xml");

        foreach (CalcualtionAnalysisDS.ReportRow row in ds.Report.Rows)
        {
            if (row.IsBestSHDSLDesignClassNull)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi darwindave, thanks for the answer.  I think that is the route I need to go, but when I tried to utilize MSDataSetGenerator, it broke on "Custom tool error: Failed to generate code. Undefined data type: 'token'."  So this sounds like another unrelated error to my post above, but any thoughts on it?  I also tried xsd.exe file.xsd /d with the same result. - Brad

Comment: I normally just drag and drop my XSD's into Visual Studio and the code is created automatically. 

You could try to create your xsd's from xml using xsd.exe just to double check your xsd is correct. 

"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\xsd" Something.xml /l:CS /classes /uri:http://something.com/xml/something /l:CS